# Не прогружается Navigation Drawer Activity Android

Tags: android

Добавил в свой проект Navigation Drawer Activity.
Хочу посмотреть макет файла меню activity_main_drawer.xml. Текст макета вижу, но вот его дизайн нет, постоянно висит надпись `Waiting for build to finish`

Посоветуйте, как исправить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: а вы используете tools в XML разметке?и билдинг действительно закончен?
лучше будет скинуть хотя бы xml-ки

Comment: Я использую стандартный (Который Android Studio сгенерировала, ничего не редактировал) Проблема в том что, приложение собирается и запускается и там все нормально, а Android StudiO не отображает макет, не удобно не много при редактировании элементов

Comment: Для начала попробуйте clean project and rebuild. Классика жанра

Comment: @Романыч не помогает